# if(isset($_FILES)) Not working in PHP

Tags: php, forms, file

i can't get the input type file value from an html form using $_FILES  , the isset($_FILES['NAME'])  to get the uploaded image  value from  the form , i have put an echo 'string' in  the first line of the isset condition  and it's not displaying it

```
 <form role="form" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <ul class="row">
                                                <li class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newpseudo" id="name" placeholder="php">
                        </label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="newmail" id="email" placeholder="*EMAIL">
                        </label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newmdp1" id="company" placeholder="*MOT DE PASSE">
                        </label>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="col-sm-12">
                                                    <label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="newmdp2" id="company" placeholder="*CONFIRMER VOTRE MOT DE PASSE">
                        </label>
                                                </li>

                                                       <li class="col-sm-12">
                                                        <label>Ajouter Photo de profil</label>
                                                        <input type="file" name="avatar" >
                                                    </li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <ul class="row">
                                                <li class="col-sm-12 no-margin">
                                                    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" id="btn_submit" onClick="proceed();" name="modifier">Mettre a jour</button>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

the PHP code  i'm trying to get it the file input value :

```
  if (isset($_FILES['avatar']) AND !empty($_FILES['avatar']['name'])) {
         echo "string";
         $taillemax = 2097152;
         $extensionsvalides = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
         if ($_FILES['avatar']['size'] <= $taillemax) {
             $extensionsUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'],'.'),1));
             if (in_array($extensionsUpload, $extensionsvalides)) {
                     $chemin ="membres/avatars/".$_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionsUpload;
                     $resultat = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $chemin);
                     if ($resultat) {
                         $updateavatar = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE memebre SET avatar = :avatar WHERE id = :id');
                         $updateavatar->execute(array('avatar'=>$_SESSION['id'].".".$extensionsUpload,'id' => $_SESSION['id']));
                               header("Location: userProfile.php?id=".$_SESSION['id']);

                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $msg = "Erreur de l'importation de votre photo de profil";
                     }
             }
             else
             {
                $msg = "votre photo de profil  doit etre de format jpg , jpeg ou png";
             }
         }
```

Comment: You have a very bad reputation,people in the past have helped you and have not marked not even one as an answer

Comment: Is the PHP code on the same page (in same file) as the form? If not, you are missing an `action` attribute on the html form.

Comment: @Brainfeeder the  php code is in the same page it's a  .php page

Comment: @D.'s i'll reply them soon

Comment: Are any errors shown?

Comment: What does the js function `proceed();` do? Are you gathering data from the fields before posting them through ajax or something? Then the problem might lay in the js code which you didn't post here...

Comment: @Brainfeeder there is no errors ,  i'm getting data from the same form  through $_POST ! but with  FILES it's not working

Comment: @yassinegharsallah can you show us the javascript `proceed()` function please?

Comment: What is with the random assortment of "glossary functions"? They may seem appropriate, but you don't always need to utilize them on case use - each has combined or specific use-case in certain situations.. here, I think you could of simplified things considerably. I mean, your not manipulating strings.. your checking and reading.

Answer (score 0):

add action for form and send data to file execute phpcode and save file
this mean you should change this line:

```
 <form role="form" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" method="post" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to:

```
 <form role="form" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" method="post" 
 enctype="multipart/form-data" action="example.php">
```